# BufferedWriter not writing entire file - only some of it

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to write elements from an ArrayList to a text document. My bufferedwriter code is as follows (with the actual filepath):

```
Path file = Paths.get("(filepath)");
    BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
        writer.write(Integer.toString(radicalsAndPositions.get(j).get(0)) + "," + Integer.toString(radicalsAndPositions.get(j).get(1)) + " , " + "\n");
    }
```

The arraylist is full up to the 100,000th element, and it generates a file, but misses values from the end. When I restrict 'j' to 10,000, I only get the first 9170 lines generated. With the full 100,000, I only get the first 99250 lines.

Restricting 'j' to 1000 gives me an empty file.

The document is generating correctly, with the correct elements, it is just ending prematurely. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close the BufferedWriter object.

`writer.close();`

It will not write your file unless you close an object of `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: Is there a reason that without the close, it only writes it partially?

Comment: The concept of the BufferedWrite is to buffer. It flushes when the buffer is full and reduces the number of separate IO opertions. It also flushes when you call flush and when you close the writer.

Comment: Yes surely there is a reason. It closes the current stream with which you are writing a file. It needs to be closed, in order to reflect the changes that you have made in a file. It also flushes the stream.

Comment: @Useablelobster you haven't accepted anybody's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Close the buffered writer when you are done to make sure the buffer is flushed.

Answer (score 2):

Also write `writer.flush()` after writing to file

```
writer.close() is also a good choice
```

Comment: calling `close()` should be enough, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close%28%29